# My Transaction has failed

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have transferred 0.11 ethereum to wallet today morning
0x5acc84a3e955Bdd76467d3348077d003f00fFB97

But it has failed. Now what i have to do. Whether the amount will be returned back to my wallet.

Transaction Hash:
0x193e584e18903a338f88d374864f3fb95553eb381b972c7d666748cffdf38acf
Status:
Fail
Block:
10391059 2024 Block Confirmations
Timestamp:
7 hrs 34 mins ago (Jul-04-2020 05:26:10 AM +UTC)
From:
0x3f1e01f65cac6cdb60ef5f7fc8f988f042949a2c
To:
Contract 0xd9f61a4a96f66afe09c6f55b72aeaf1590ac8495
Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]
Value:
0 Ether ($0.00)
Transaction Fee:
0.01265 Ether ($2.86)
Click to see More
Private Note:
To access the Private Note feature, you must be Logged In

Comment: So what exactly is the question then?

Comment: If the transaction failed, no ether has been moved.

Comment: If you have sent the transaction from an exchange then you have to ask their customer support. This applies to any type of wallet where you do not control the private key.

Answer (score 1):

Since the transaction reverted, no ETH was sent. The only ETH you lost was the transaction fee. If your wallet is appearing to be missing funds, you'll have to contact the developer and/or maintainer (Metamask, exchange, etc.) of your wallet as it likely has a UI bug.